# CiviCRM Email seems not working

Tags: civievent, drupal, civimail, email

I am using CiviCRM 5.9.1 on Drupal 7.56, and on a pantheon server, we use mail() for our outgoing mail. And it is giving an error after sending a test email. Please refer the screenshot

[image]

I have enabled debugging and error handling. checked ConfigAndLog file. It is showing this.

```
Mar 02 01:26:56  [info] Ignoring exception thrown by nullHandler: , mail() returned failure

Mar 02 01:26:56  [info] $backTrace = #0 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(962): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::nullHandler(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(577): PEAR_Error->__construct("mail() returned failure", NULL, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#3 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(236): PEAR::_raiseError(NULL, "mail() returned failure")
#4 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Mail/mail.php(176): PEAR::__callStatic("raiseError", (Array:1))
#5 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(670): Mail_mail->send("\"Mr. Kevin c\" ", (Array:10), "--=_c4909b79b1625e743ccf0766d4dcdc82\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\nConten...", "1912")
#6 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(571): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob->deliverGroup((Array:1), Object(CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing), Object(Mail_mail), "20190302012656", (Array:0))
#7 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(199): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob->deliver(Object(Mail_mail), (Array:13))
#8 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Mailing.php(694): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::runJobs((Array:13))
#9 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_mailing_send_test((Array:10))
#10 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(169): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#11 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
#12 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(77): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("mailing", "send_test", (Array:10), NULL)
#13 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Subscriber/ChainSubscriber.php(211): Civi\API\Kernel->run("mailing", "send_test", (Array:10))
#14 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Subscriber/ChainSubscriber.php(73): Civi\API\Subscriber\ChainSubscriber->callNestedApi(Object(Civi\API\Kernel), (Array:36), (Array:5), "create", "Mailing", 3)
#15 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(184): Civi\API\Subscriber\ChainSubscriber->onApiRespond(Object(Civi\API\Event\RespondEvent), "civi.api.respond", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#16 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(46): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:4), "civi.api.respond", Object(Civi\API\Event\RespondEvent))
#17 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(47): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("civi.api.respond", Object(Civi\API\Event\RespondEvent))
#18 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(276): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("civi.api.respond", Object(Civi\API\Event\RespondEvent))
#19 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(171): Civi\API\Kernel->respond(Object(Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider), (Array:9), (Array:5))
#20 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
#21 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Mailing", "create", (Array:36), NULL)
#22 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(311): civicrm_api("Mailing", "create", (Array:36))
#23 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(548): CRM_Utils_REST::process((Array:3), (Array:36))
#24 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(275): CRM_Utils_REST::ajax()
#25 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#26 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#27 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#28 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "rest")
#29 /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/index.php(22): menu_execute_active_handler()
#30 {main}
```

I have checked the from email address settings. It is fine, we are using example@domain.

This is happening for all event registration. event receipt or confirmation email will not send to the user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When I fetch the Bounces log inside the Administer >>system setting >>scheduled jobs >> fetch job logs - it is showing,                                                                         Full message: 
Finished execution of Bounces fetcher with the result: Failure, Error message: A fatal error was triggered: Could not connect to MailStore for return@hgs.org@imap.gmail.com
Error message: 

An error occurred while sending or receiving mail. The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password: A0001 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure).